# sql string error expecting 1 parameter but i do set 1 parameter

Tags: php

i have a problem with my code in php.
The problem i have is this error:

> Warning: wordwrap() expects parameter 1 to be string

I have searched for other answers but i can't find why mine is not working.
Im getting my `$content` from my database with `$content = showContent($id);`
My code:

**In Function.php**

```
function showContent($id)
{
$db = connectDb();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `contentId` = $id";
$obj = $db->prepare($sql);
$obj->bindValue(":id", $id);
if($obj->execute() && $obj->rowCount() > 0)
{
    return $obj->fetch();
}
}
```

**In my index.php**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menu">
    <?php

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $id = $row['contentId'];
    echo "<a href='index.php?id=$id'>";
    echo $row['contentName'];
    echo "</a><br>";

    echo "<br>";
}


    ?>

</div>
<div id="content">
    <?php
    echo "<h2>$content[contentName]</h2>";
    $contentw = wordwrap($content, 50, "\n", true);
    echo $contentw['contentw'];
    ?>

</div>
```

**edit** i made a type in the sql statement, i ment to place :id instead of $id

Comment: You're preparing incorrectly.. `$sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE contentId = $id";` you need to replace the `$id` with `:id`

Answer (score 0):

Wordwrap function Wraps a string to a given number of characters.

In your case, you're passing an array in the first argument so It does not work and throw the warning. Try to pass the string in the first argument and check it out again.

Please visit below link for more details:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php